# How to balance style and efficiecny when accessing two-dimensional array, vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

`CObject` below has vertex arrays and buffers and various other member variables.  The question is, how should I access the data in `CAgent` from `CAnotherClass` especially with the two-dimensional array (currently vectors) concerning style and also efficiency within and near openGL ES rendering callback function. The vectors of sub-objects are normally reasonable but could get as large as 32,000.

```
class CObject
{
    // vertex arrays, buffers, and data
    int val;
public:
    int     GetValue(){ return val; }
    void    SetValue( int v ){ val = v; }
};

class CAgent
{
    friend class CAnotherClass; // may I, since like an extension?

    enum ObjType { a, b, c, };

    std::vector< CObject * >                m_Objects;    // implementation fills these
    std::vector< std::vector< CObject * > > m_SubObjects; // each object above has n sub-objects

    // for option B below
    CObject *     GetSubObjectN( int type, int n ) { return m_SubObjects[type][n]; }
    std::vector< CObject * > & GetSubObjects( int type ) { return m_SubObjects[type]; }
};

class CAgentSub : public CAgent
{
    class CAnotherClass * m_AgentExtension; // really just an extension of this

    void Render( double timestamp ); // implementation calls CAnotherClass::Render()
};


class CAnotherClass
{
    CAgentSub *                 m_Agent;

    CObject *                   m_CurrentObject;                // for convenience
    std::vector< CObject * > *  m_CurrentSubObjects;

    int                         m_ObjectType;                   // or this way

    void SetObjectType( int type )
    {
        m_CurrentObject =       m_Agent->m_Objects[type];       // for convenience
        m_CurrentSubObjects =   &m_Agent->m_SubObjects[type];

        m_ObjectType =          type;                           // or this way?

    }

    void DoSomethingInteresting()
    {
        int val = -1;
        int startVal = 0;

        // option A
        for ( int n = 0; n < m_CurrentSubObjects->size(); ++n )
        {
            val = (*m_CurrentSubObjects)[n]->GetValue();        // this is what I'm doing but seems cumbersome
                                                                // and not that easy to read
            (*m_CurrentSubObjects)[n]->SetValue( startVal );
        }

        // option B
        for ( int n = 0; n < m_Agent->GetSubObjects(m_ObjectType).size(); ++n )
            val = m_Agent->GetSubObjectN( m_ObjectType, n )->GetValue();

        // option C
        for ( int n = 0; n < m_Agent->m_SubObjects[m_ObjectType].size(); ++n )
            val = m_Agent->m_SubObjects[m_ObjectType][n]->GetValue();

        // option D
        for ( std::vector<CObject *>::iterator it  = m_Agent->m_SubObjects[m_ObjectType].begin();
                                               it != m_Agent->m_SubObjects[m_ObjectType].end();
                                             ++it )
        {
            (*it)->SetValue( startVal );
        }

        // setting data at various indexes

        int index = 23;

        (*m_CurrentSubObjects)[index]->SetValue( startVal );

        m_Agent->GetSubObjectN( m_ObjectType, index )->SetValue( startVal );

        m_Agent->m_SubObjects[m_ObjectType][index]->SetValue( startVal );

        std::vector<CObject *>::iterator nth = m_Agent->m_SubObjects[m_ObjectType].begin() + index;
        (*nth)->SetValue( startVal );

    }

    void    Render( double timestamp );
};
```

Comment: You are entering the land of premature optimization potentially. Have you profiled the code to determine if vector access is a performance bottleneck?

Comment: No, I will look into that. But it still leaves the question about what would be the best style.

Comment: Style is a bit broad and subjective. I personally create typedefs of STL iterators for containers I'm using so I have less typing in for loops. At some point it usually becomes better to just make an object with various members and methods for whatever you're doing rather than using complex nested STL containers. It's mostly preference ...

Comment: Clarity always beats efficiency, until you are certain that you have a bottleneck.

Comment: So then which of the above do you find most clear, setting type, setting a pointer to vector to work from, accessing the array directly or using accessors, using iterator or [] operator?

Comment: I'm getting better with the Xcode (now 5) profiling for leaks and allocations but I couldn't get a grip on how to isolate bottlenecks.  I can't find the Counter trace instrument referred to.  I know I could push the numbers to the point they could affect performance.  It's not that easy for me to learn how to make sense of the instruments.